# Proxy servlet web-inf/web.xml on sap server to call external REST

Tags: javascript, ajax, proxy, sapui5

To develop a custom SAPUI5 / Fiori App, we need to consume a RESTful webservice from another server. Avoiding CORS (Cross-Origin) error we locally use eclipse, that supports us with the "UI5 Simple Proxy Servlet".

```
    <!-- ==============================================================     -->
    <!-- UI5 proxy servlet                                              -->
    <!-- ============================================================== -->

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SimpleProxyServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sap.ui5.proxy.SimpleProxyServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SimpleProxyServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/proxy/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

If I test the app on the SAP Application Server it does not work with the following call using the proxy-servlet in the URL:

```
var serviceUrl = 'proxy/<host>/<service>/rest/api/content/' + contentID + '?parameters';
        $.ajax({
               type: 'GET',         
               url : serviceUrl,
               headers: {
                   'Authorization': "Basic " + btoa('USERNAME' + ":" + 'PWD') },
               dataType: 'json',
               indexValue: {    param1:oView,
                                param2:oModel
                           },
               crossDomain: true,
               success: function(data,textStatus,ErrorHandler) {
                   alert("Success");
               },
               error: function(ErrorHandler,textStatus,errorThrown) {
                   alert("Error");
               }
```

Running it without the proxy/, with Chrome and option "--disable-web-security" the RESTcall works fine.

Is there a way to use the proxy-servlet on the SAP Netweaver Application server?

Comment: If your company is the owner/developer of the other webservice I think you can add Access-Control-Allow-Origin parameter to the response header. Otherwise the only solution would be a proxy server, e.g. SAP Web Dispatcher.

Comment: Unfortunately, the REST service provider is a cloud service and does yet support an option to adjust the headers.

Answer (score 2):

The reason why it doesn't work is because it is not meant to work. In [the official documentation](https://help.sap.com/viewer/468a97775123488ab3345a0c48cadd8f/7.4.19/en-US/2d3f5fb63a2f4090942375df80abc39f.html) for it, SAP states:

> Be aware that due to security reasons the SimpleProxyServlet is restricted to local testing purposes only. It can only be used for local host scenarios (accessing Gateway services to avoid cross-domain issues) and will not work when deployed on an application server. For productive use, refer to a mature proxy servlet.

Of course, you can ignore this and do it anyway. I am not sure how exactly they are preventing the servlet from being part of your deployed application, but I am sure you can get it to work in one way or another:

- If the JAR that contains it is not actually included in the WAR / EAR, then you could try to force it in there (e.g. change the scope of the maven dependency or change the build itself).
- Worst cast scenario, the AS simply "blacklists" the servlet. In this case, you can always build a small "delegate" servlet around SAP's servlet.
- If even that does not work, then copy-paste might be your friend. You will anyway not get support from SAP for this servlet, as the documentation specifically tells you to not use it in production.

But I would not go this route. In my opinion, you have three main solutions aside from using the SAP servlet:

- Add the CORS headers on the REST service that you are consuming. This assumes that you have access to it (which may not be the case). If it is indeed possible to do it, this should be the preferred solution due to performance considerations.
- Use another "proxy servlet" implementation in embedded mode to mimic the setup that you are using locally. You could take a look at e.g. [Netflix Zuul](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-netflix/multi/multi__router_and_filter_zuul.html#netflix-zuul-reverse-proxy).
- Deploy a separate application which has the sole concern of acting as such a reverse proxy for all the apps on the AS. The benefit would be that you could more easily reuse and manage such a setup (i.e. the same Java app would proxy several REST services and serve multiple UI apps). Again, for achieving this I would recommend using some library like Zuul.

Comment: Unfortunately, the REST service provider does not yet support an option to adjust the headers.